# Why are UserClaims not added to the auth cookie in Asp.net core Identity flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

I've been having this problem getting UserClaims from the ASP.Net auth database to be actually included in the auth cookie that gets set on the client, and subsequently I can't use the claim in my access control `Authorize` attributes on the API controller.

Reproduce, minimal code example

1. VS 2022 Create new project from template *ASP.Net Core With Angular*
   using .NET 5.0 and Authentication type as *Individual Accounts*
2. Do command `dotnet ef database update` to create the default auth
   database.
3. Build and Run the app, create user and log in.
4. Check the "Fetch data" page, to see the API fetch in action.
5. In the newly created auth database, add a claim to the
   AspNetUserClaims table, with the "role" schema, similar to

| Id | UserId | ClaimType | ClaimValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0282683c-47c2-4ac1-976c-74db0b34bcff | http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role | IAmTheWallrus |

1. Log out from the web app
2. In the `WeatherForcastController`, change `[Authorize]` to
   `[Authorize(Roles = "IAmTheWallrus")]` (I have to stop and rebuild,
   but that's another problem).
3. (Run and) Login to the app, try to open the Fetch data page now.

I just get a *Loading...* on the page and a *403 Forbidden* in the console.

In fact, if I inspect the cookie for the session I don't see this new *IAmTheWallrus* claim anywhere.

Now, I admit, I'm not very familiar with the auth cookie stuff, but from what I understand, the "role" should be added to the cookie, so it would be visible in the cookie inspector in Firefox, for example, or viewable at https://jwt.io/

The example above is just a minimal working code sample, I'm actually running my app with the Scaffolded code for the Auth pages, where I've done as the instructions say:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-and-update-user-claims.
Specifically adding the `_userManager.AddClaimAsync` and `_signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);` stuff. I've been trying for a while now, different aspects of that instructions page going back and forth, but I can't get my claims to do anything more than appear in this table in the database, they are seemingly never added to the actual cookie so I can't use them to access control my API endpoints.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was the login successful? or did you checked where you are assigning the user and hows is your startup.cs looks like? Please share above infomation.

Comment: Yes, the login was successful, and the startup.cs looks just like it does in the template (in the minimal working example) I don't think I can find the template on github somewhere, but it's just the standard one that happens if you create a new project from the "ASP.NET Core with Angular" template in Visual Studio

Comment: Could you share `_userManager.AddClaimAsync` details how you are binding and assigning to cookie?

Comment: In the minimal code example, I'm using the Identity pages unchanged (unscaffolded), so I think this is the code: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V5/Account/Login.cshtml.cs In my code I've tried many of the methods outlined in these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-and-update-user-claims, but the cookie does not include the claims, even if I add them manually with _userManager.AddClaimAsync and then _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync

Comment: AFAIK The claims come straight from the `AspNetUserClaims` table. If they aren't added through code at registration, they won't be added to the ClaimsIdentity at the `SigninManager.SigninAsync` calls